# Error running mapreduce sample in hadoop 0.23.6

Tags: hadoop

I deployed Hadoop 0.23.6 in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I am able to copy files across and do file manipulation. I am using YARN for mapreduce.

I am getting the following error, when I am trying to run any mapreduce application using the hadoop-mapreduce-examples-0.23.6.jar

Command used:
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-0.23.6.jar randomwriter -Dmapreduce.randomwriter.mapsperhost=1 -Dmapreduce.job.user.name=$USER -Dmapreduce.randomwriter.bytespermap=10000 -Ddfs.blocksize=536870912 -Ddfs.block.size=536870912 -libjars hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-0.23.6.jar output

Hadoop version: 0.23.6

**Container launch failed for container_1364342550899_0001_01_000002 : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid shuffle port number -1 returned for attempt_1364342550899_0001_m_000000_0**

Answer (score 2):

Verify your yarn-site.xml configuration. You need to have below properties configured.

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce.shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
```

For more details, have look at jira 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-2983?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Comment: I already had the properties in the yarn-site.xml. I then tried reformatting the name node, but still didn't work. I finally downloaded the hadoop 2.x version and copied all the *-site.xml from the existing hadoop 0.23.6 and it worked.